# How can I describe a square in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: ios, opengl-es2, objective-c

I need to draw a Tic-Tac-Toe board in Xcode using OpenGL ES 2.0. I am new to graphics programming and can't find good information on drawing a square in opengl es in iOS. I looked at Ray's tutorials, which are good, however he covers drawing a rotating cube. All I want is a square; how can I describe a square for OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0) tutorial from Ray covers preparation of the OpenGL render pipeline and the setup required to describe a square. It's about halfway down.

Specifically, to draw a square you'll want to draw two triangles. Ray's code organizes them like this:

[image: Ray Wenderlich square definition]

That's four vertices and six indices (two sets of three):

```
Vector2 vertices[] = {
  Vector2(1, -1), Vector2(1, 1), Vector2(-1, 1), Vector2(-1, -1)
};

short indices[] = {
  0, 1, 2,
  2, 3, 0
};
```

(Ray's tutorial uses 3D positions and also provides color information, which I'm excluding for brevity.)

Store this data into the appropriate buffers using `glBufferData` (assuming you've previously created both buffers):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(Vector2), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(short), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then use `glDrawElements` to submit the draw command to the card.

Note that you'll likely need to adjust the coordinates of the vertices depending on your current projection matrix (et cetera); the provided coordinates will fill the screen when the transformation pipeline is configured with a series of identity matrices, but is only really suitable for initially bootstrapping rendering.